# Can I find the number of sides of a polygon without using interior angle?

Tags: geometry

Can I just use one exterior angle to find the number of sides? 
Sorry if that was too basic  trying to understand polygons and sides/ angles relations

Edit: regular polygons

Comment: Do you mean a regular polygon? All sides and angles equal?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant forgot to mention that

Comment: You cannot choose an exterior angle arbitrarily in order to get an $n$ sided regular polygon... It has to be $2 \pi/n$ only.

Comment: yeah so it only works when 360 is divided by that exterior angle right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. One exterior (or equivalently, interior) angle is certainly not enough. If you happen to pick the right angle of a right triangle, you cannot distinguish that from a rectangle.

Comment: So if i was given an exterior angle (for example 30 degrees) of a regular polygon i cant just divide 360 by 30?

Comment: Ah, now you say *regular* polygons

Comment: I edited that , I just forgot to add it

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not. However if you were given a regular polygon then $360/$*exterior angle* will probably give you the required answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you I get it now, I forgot to mention regular polygons

Comment: Upvote answer if you find it helpful and welcome

Comment: I did but I have less than 15 reputations so it doesnt show